# my program closes and i don't know why

Tags: batch-file

help when i open my program it closes and i don't know whats wrong?!

```html
@echo off
title test
echo wat is het wachtwoord?
SET /p hoi =:
if "%hoi%" == "hallo"
goto idk

:idk
xcopy /s "E:\Windows.old\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.3DBuilder_11.1.9.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\test" "D:\"
pause()

:exit
EXIT
```

Comment: Don't double-click to open the batch file, open a command prompt window instead, manoeuvre to the path of the batch file using `cd /D` and type the name of the batch-file to execute it; after having removed the line `@echo off`, you will see all the output and error messages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
if "%hoi%" == "hallo" goto idk

:: Note the `goto` must be on the same line as the `if`
:: Note also that if the above test fails, batch will simply continue
:: executing commands, so the next command to be executed
:: will be the "xcopy" following

:idk
xcopy /s "E:\Windows.old\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.3DBuilder_11.1.9.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\test" "D:\"
::
:: PAUSE takes no parameters. The `()` will cause the `pause` not 
:: to be recognised - `cmd` will attempt to execute a command "pause()"
:: and fail.
pause
...
```